# How to take info from an array 3 integers at a time

Tags: java

I have an integer array, that reads 300 numbers from a file:

```
        int [] dates = new int[300];
```

I am trying to take every 3 integers, and add them together, then move on to the next 3. I place the first 3 positions, 0, 1, and 2 here:

```
int j = dates[0];
int k = dates[1];
int l = dates[2];
```

from here I add them together into another variable. my question is, how can I move onto the next three smartly? or am I doing this completely wrong from the beginning?

Comment: You use a `for` loop with an increment of 3?

Answer (score 2):

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i += 3 ) {
    array[i];
    array[i+1];
    array[i+2];
}
```